# Codigniter error when calling in class

Tags: php, codeigniter

my model authors function is like that

```
class Authors  extends CI_Model{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function available_username($text)
    {
        $this->db->query("SELECT username FROM tbl_users WHERE username='$text' LIMIT 1");
        if($this->db->affected_rows() == 0)
        {
            return TRUE;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

i am calling this function in my class like that

```
   $CI =& get_instance();
   $CI->load->model('authors');
   $username = "Danny";
   if($CI->authors->available_username($username) == TRUE)
   {
       $fUsername = TRUE;
   }
   else
   {
       $fUsername = FALSE;
   }
```

I think its right approach but i am getting error of model

```
    Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object
```

Comment: Post more detail of your model class

Comment: @Hashem Qolami the model is working fine when I use it in Controller.

Comment: I was not loading the database library that's why it was causing error. I am sorry for trouble. Thanx everyone

Comment: Nice to see it has been fixed, consider autoloading the database driver :)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to call/load your model using $CI =& get_instance();

On a controller you can load like this:

$this->load->model("yourModelName", "alias"); // alias optional

Then, you can use the method by using: $this->yourModelName->method();

Now lets talk about the error: It happens when you put in IF() statement a complex call like you are doing.
Instead, do this:

```
     $stuff = $CI->authors->available_username($username);
       if($stuff == TRUE)
       {
           $fUsername = TRUE;
       }
       else
       {
           $fUsername = FALSE;
       }
```

When you put this kind of statement on a variable, magic happens!

Dont forget to tell me if it works :D

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you did not load the DB.

Check config/autoload.php

And see you have loaded the DB, Its not necessary to load DB from autoload but its usual.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```